# Out of memory! Perl

Tags: perl

I am using 28 files in one perl program.
Each file is about 2Mb in size.
I have taken them into 28 arrays. and printing in 28 output files.
Each output file contains all the arrays concatenated , except current file array. 
After 11 output files, each of about 70 MB size,
**Out of memory!** msg is coming .
How to increase the memory limit.

What I tried is :
I closed each file handler after fetching the data into an array.  but no use....
Please suggest solutions.

Comment: "How to increase the memory limit." Buy more ram, but this is not the best way to deal with your problem.  I'm guessing it's the way you are generating your output; could you show the code for that please

Comment: You're probably hitting against the 2GB or 3GB of available address space a 32-bit process has. Why you'd hit that with the numbers you gave is rather mysterious. You could increase the available address space by using a 64-bit build of Perl, but that's probably not the way to go in this case.

Comment: If you're not doing heavy calculations with the data, just open a file, read it, print it to the new file while reading it, close it, open the next one, repeat, close the output, and so on. Only put the data in a lexical scope inside the reading loop. That will take a lot longer, but safe the memory problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have four files `A B C D`, you then want to create four files so that
File 1 contains `B C D`,
File 2 contains `A C D`,
File 3 contains `A B D`, and
File 4 contains `A B C`.

What you are currently doing is loading every file into an array (just using strings would spare a little memory), and then printing each output file consecutively.

You could also open all output files, then open each input file in sequence and print it to every non-corresponding output file. This keeps only one file in memory at any time.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @in =  qw(A B C D);
my @out = qw(1 2 3 4);

my @outhandles = map {open my $fh, ">", $_ or die $!; $fh} @out;

for my $i (0 .. $#in) {
   open my $fh, "<", $in[$i] or die $!;
   my $content = do {local $/; <$fh>};
   for my $j (0 .. $#outhandles) {
      print {$outhandles[$j]} $content unless $i == $j;
   }
}
```

Memory could be reduced further if you'd say `print {$outhandles[$j]} $_ while <$fh>` instead of slurping the input files.

#### Test

```
$ mkdir test; cd test;
$ for file in {A..D}; do echo $file >$file; done
$ perl ../script.pl
$ ls
1  2  3  4  A  B  C  D
$ for file in `ls`; do echo == $file; cat $file; done
== 1
B
C
D
== 2
A
C
D
== 3
A
B
D
== 4
A
B
C
== A
A
== B
B
== C
C
== D
D
```

Comment: The problem is solved but I wanted a newline after each file content (It is coming in continuation). I cudnt manually insert \n in your script.

Comment: @Nari All my test files were terminated with a `\n` so the problem didn't arise. If you want to insert a newline after each file, `print $content, "\n"` inside the loop or similar.